# Spring Rabbit Queue Xml: NoSuchBeanDefinition when Getting Property from 'Getter Bean'

Tags: java, spring, spring-rabbit, xmlbeans

I'm configuring Spring Rabbit using an xml file for spring rabbit beans and configuration.

We use our own propertyGetter class to retrieve properties.  In the spring rabbit xml below, it works everywhere except for one place.  Why is this?

Below is the xml.  The 'propertyGetter.get(...)' method being called is returning a String 'my.queue', but it seems that the RabbitMq xsd parser is trying to obtain a bean. (?).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit-1.4.xsd">

        <!-- This has the 'propertyGetter' bean -->
        <import resource="**/applicationContext.xml"/>

        <!--  RabbitMQ -->
        <rabbit:connection-factory id="rabbitConnectionFactory" addresses="#{propertyGetter.get('rabbitMq.hostName')}" username="#{propertyGetter.get('rabbitMq.userName')}" password="#{propertyGetter.get('rabbitMq.password')}" virtual-host="#{propertyGetter.get('rabbitMq.vHost')}"/>
        <rabbit:admin connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory"/>

        <!-- RabbitMQ Template -->
        <rabbit:template id="rabbitTemplate" connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory" message-converter="messageConverter" exchange="#{propertyGetter.get('rabbitMq.exchange')}"/>


        /*******************************************
         *
         *    THIS IS THE ONLY PLACE IT DOESN'T WORK
         *    <rabbit:queue name=""
         *        It does seem to get value 'my.queue'
         *        but the exception that's posted
         *        below indicates it's trying to 
         *        construct a bean!  Why is this?
        *******************************************/
        <!-- RabbitMQ Queue Definitions -->
        <!--<rabbit:queue name="my.queue" >--> <!--THIS WORKS-->
        <rabbit:queue name="#{propertyGetter.get('rabbitMq.queue.name')}" > <!--THIS DOESN'T-->
            <rabbit:queue-arguments>
                <entry key="x-ha-policy" value="all"/>
            </rabbit:queue-arguments>
        </rabbit:queue>

        <!-- RabbitMQ Exchange and Binding Definition -->
        <rabbit:direct-exchange name="#{propertyGetter.get('rabbitMq.exchange')}">
            <rabbit:bindings>
                <rabbit:binding key="#{propertyGetter.get('rabbitMq.routing.key')}" queue="#{propertyGetter.get('rabbitMq.queue.name')}"/>
            </rabbit:bindings>
        </rabbit:direct-exchange>

        <!-- Listeners -->
        <rabbit:listener-container id="listener" connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory" concurrency="3" max-concurrency="5" requeue-rejected="false">
            <rabbit:listener ref="eventNotificationAdapter" queues="#{propertyGetter.get('rabbitMq.queue.name')}" priority="#{propertyGetter.get('rabbitMq.queue.priority')}" />
        </rabbit:listener-container>

        <!-- Message Listener Adapters -->
        <bean id="eventNotificationAdapter" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter">
            <constructor-arg name="delegate" ref="myQueueConsumer"/>
            <constructor-arg name="messageConverter" ref="messageConverter"/>
            <property name="defaultListenerMethod" value="process"/>
        </bean>

        <bean id="messageConverter" class="org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.JsonMessageConverter"/>

</beans>
```

The exception when the app is first initialized is'NoSuchBeanDefinitionException', but I'm not sure why whatever is parsing the xml is expecting a bean, when the method call is returning a String.

Here's the stack trace I get when trying to deploy the app:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.BindingFactoryBean#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean '#{propertyGetter.get('rabbitMq.queue.name')}' while setting bean property 'destinationQueue'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'my.queue' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:736)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(SpringContextLoaderListener.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5017)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5531)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1095)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1930)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'my.queue' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1168)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:281)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 29 more
```

Other notes:
This is an xml file that uses the spring-rabbit-1.3.xsd

The solution does not use spring properties.  This is for managing properties another way.

Comment: Could you please add applicationContext.xml where propertyGetter is initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are two different things.

For a `<bean/>`, the `name` attribute is an alias for the bean name. If no `id` is provided, the first `name` is used as the id.

For a `<queue/>` the `name` attribute is the name of the queue in the rabbitmq broker; the `id` is always the bean name and, if not present, a unique bean name is generated.

There is some existing logic to register the `name` as an alias, but that only works when the value is known at parse time (as you have found).

In fact, this use of aliasing is incorrect and causes other problems - for example you can't have an exchange and queue with the same `name` - see [this JIRA for a discussion about that](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-617).

To solve that issue, we are considering removing the aliasing altogether and requiring an `id` attribute to give the bean a name.

I believe you can work-around your issue by giving the queue an `id` and referencing that in your listener container `queues` attribute, or change the container to use `queue-names` instead.

Comment: This worked!  I was still able to use the propertyGetter in the queue itself, but just added an id and also used it in the listener container and exchange binding.  I forgot to mention, that the xml in my question works using a properties file and ${my.prop}.  Not sure why that doesn't cause the same runtime error.

Comment: Yes, there is logic in the bean factory to resolve placeholders in aliases, but there is no equivalent for SpEL expressions.